# Read qualified yaml file with prefix without using annotations or xml

Tags: java, spring, yaml, properties-file

My use case is a bit oddball but basically, I'd like to read a portion of a yaml file and map it to the appropriate java object in a spring application. This is a pretty common and trivial operation in spring (just use @ConfigurationProperties ).

However, in my case, I'd like to accomplish this reading earlier in the lifecycle i.e. by the time the BeanFactoryPostProcessor hooks in - in order to use the instructions specified in yml to dynamically create a number of beans.

I can get this working with application.properties but not with application.yml

I was hoping to use yml in order leverage mapping part of the yml to POJO and also utilize hierarchical mapping files and data structures (lists, maps etc).

Here's an example of how to read application.properties. https://blog.pchudzik.com/201705/dynamic-beans/

I set up a simple skeleton project at https://github.com/balamuru/yaml-loader to try out different techniques. 
 Any ideas ?

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SampleDataConfig.class)
class ConfigurableBeanFactory implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, InitializingBean {
    private List<String> beanInstances = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        final BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory;

        Map<String, SampleDataConfig> beans = beanFactory.getBeansOfType(SampleDataConfig.class);
        System.err.println("");

        beanInstances.forEach(instance -> {
            registry.registerBeanDefinition(instance, BeanDefinitionBuilder
                    .rootBeanDefinition(SampleDataConfig.class)
                    .addConstructorArgValue(instance)
                    .getBeanDefinition());
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
//        this.beanInstances = asList(PropertiesLoaderUtils
//                .loadProperties(new ClassPathResource("/application.properties"))
//                .getProperty("dynamic-beans.instances", "")
//                .split(","));

        /**
         * Rather than reading from application.properties,
         * I would like to be able to load up the relevant prefix qualified segments (com.foo.bar.stuff) mapping to my POJO (SampleDataConfig,class)
         * loaded from application.yml
         */
    }

}
```

Internally, spring uses the following mechanism, but I was hoping there is an easier way to leverage this without re-inventing the spring :)

```
public class ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor ...{
.
.

    private void postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName,
            ConfigurationProperties annotation) {
        Object target = bean;
        PropertiesConfigurationFactory<Object> factory = new PropertiesConfigurationFactory<Object>(
                target);
        factory.setPropertySources(this.propertySources);
        factory.setValidator(determineValidator(bean));
        // If no explicit conversion service is provided we add one so that (at least)
        // comma-separated arrays of convertibles can be bound automatically
        factory.setConversionService(this.conversionService == null
                ? getDefaultConversionService() : this.conversionService);
        if (annotation != null) {
            factory.setIgnoreInvalidFields(annotation.ignoreInvalidFields());
            factory.setIgnoreUnknownFields(annotation.ignoreUnknownFields());
            factory.setExceptionIfInvalid(annotation.exceptionIfInvalid());
            factory.setIgnoreNestedProperties(annotation.ignoreNestedProperties());
            if (StringUtils.hasLength(annotation.prefix())) {
                factory.setTargetName(annotation.prefix()); //====> use annotation prefix
            }
        }
        try {
            factory.bindPropertiesToTarget(); //===> bind properties
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```java
YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("application.yml"));
configProperty = yaml.getObject();
Set<Object> keys = configProperty.keySet();
```

Below is my YAML configuration, which looks like:

```
template:
  config:
    broker-urls:
    - tcp://127.0.0.1:61616
    - tcp://127.0.0.1:61617
    - tcp://127.0.0.1:61618
    qeues:
    - Test
    - Demo
    - Qeue3
```

After applying above code you will get converted properties like below:

```
template.config.broker-urls[0]=tcp://127.0.0.1:61616
template.config.broker-urls[1]=tcp://127.0.0.1:61617
template.config.broker-urls[1]=tcp://127.0.0.1:61618

template.config.qeues[0]=Test
template.config.qeues[1]=Demo
template.config.qeues[1]=Qeue3
```